# Getting Things Done In Activities Using Async Tasks Vs. Calling Service

Tags: android

When something asynchronous needs to be done it is often recommended to put this in a service, maybe an intent service.  Great. However, it is also not recommended to startup an activity from a service ...  So when asynchronous response comes back inside the service perhaps the user is on a different screen.  Then their is the whole aspect of binding to services ...  One is left wondering which way is better and why?  I mean services are cool but there is the binding to service call and there is also the issue that services should not have callbacks into activities.  So which way is better.  What is the criteria for using an AsyncTask vs. a Service to do async work? Also there is requestForResult() option too ...

Answer (score 3):

The criterias are basically,

1. Do you need to update some data regularly or continue some task (android gives an example of a music player where the music continues even when no activities are visible) even when your application activities no longer run? Use service here.
2. Do you have a need where your data or some task needs to be run by multiple applications? In such case the applications need to bind to your service and access the info.
3. Do you have a case there is IPC involved? Use a service.
4. Do you have a case where all u need to do is do a heavy task like downloading data, some kick ass algorithm which takes time? Do all heavy tasks in a background thread and update the UI once completed. use an AsyncTask.

Asynctask is simple. Used mostly in your activities to do heavy tasks in a separate thread to avoid ANR.

Services on the other hand is used to do tasks which needs to run even when your app is not running, other app needs to bind to update data, you need the updated data before displaying your activity.

I am sure there are more criterias, but these are just a few that just came to me.